# IPython command not found Terminal OSX. Pip installed

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal, ipython

Using Python 2.7 installed via homebrew. I then used pip to install IPython. So, IPython seems to be installed under:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

I think this is true because there is a IPython directory and ipython egg.

However, when I type ipython in the terminal I get:

-bash: ipython: command not found

I do not understand why this ONLY happens with IPython and not with python? Also, how do I fix this? What path should I add in .bashrc? And how should I add?

Currently, my .bashrc reads:

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/

Thanks!

Comment: Is it actually running the python you installed, as it already had python before you installed another version of it.

Comment: I added the comment to the main question.

Comment: Find out where the `ipython` script was installed, and if necessary symlink it to somewhere on your PATH.

Comment: What is it that I look for "ipython installation"? Do I look for .app or .egg? And what command do I use to symlink? Thanks!

Comment: From bash you have to start ipython with the following command: ipython-2.7 (and NOT just with ipython)

Comment: For quick reference to answer below by Luna Kong: specify a python module (such as IPython) using the -m parameter: 'python -m IPython'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this issue too, the following worked for me and seems like a clean simple solution:

pip uninstall ipython

pip install ipython

I'm running mavericks and latest pip

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just installed Anaconda and got everything to work.

Comment: For some users, doing just `pip install ipython` might give an `access denied` error. In that case, you need: `sudo pip install ipython`

Comment: Using `pip install -U --user --force ipython` worked through.

Answer (score 22):

Check IPython whether is installed by below command:

```
$python -m IPython
```

[image]
If you got this result as above picture.

Then run this command on terminal and add into **~/.bash_profile** file

```
$alias ipython='python -m IPython'
```

So try run "ipython" again on terminal. It works fine for me.

*Reference topics:*

[ipython on MacOS 10.10 - command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856194/ipython-on-macos-10-10-command-not-found)

[iPython installed but not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441943/ipython-installed-but-not-found)

Comment: just had similar issue when updating from Mac OSX Mojave to Catalina and changing to zsh as a standard shell, even in the bash version of it the ipython command was broken, adding alias ipython="python3 -m IPython" to ~/.zshrc fixes it

Answer (score 4):

Create `.pydistutils.cfg` in your homedir with following content:

```
[global]
verbose=1

[install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin

[easy_install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin
```

And then: `pip install -U --user ipython`. Of course `$HOME/bin` must be in your `$PATH`. Packages are going to be installed in `$HOME/Library/Python`, so user only, not system wide.

Comment: Hmm....when I do the pip command as you suggested I get:

no such option: --user  #I added my account name as user, obviously!

Any ideas why the command fails?

Comment: `pip` needs to be installed into homedir too. Run `easy_install --user pip`, to got one in your `$HOME/bin` and then --user option will be enabled.

Comment: Wait, when I try EXACTLY the command you suggested I have the following:
pip install -U --user ipython
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: OK, I did the following: easy_install --user pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.3.1
Processing pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Adding pip 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /Users/XXXX/bin
Installing pip-2.7 script to /Users/XXXX/bin where XXXX is the username. I also have the .pydistutils.cfg file in my home directory and still ipython command is not recognized.

Comment: The run again: `pip install -U --user --force ipython`, to get it reinstalled and scripts put in `$HOME/bin`.

Comment: Yay! That works. Thanks SO MUCH for your patience and perseverance.

Comment: Found this necessary again on El Capitan; thanks for the detailed instructions.

Answer (score 4):

Try run `brew install ipython`:

[image]

then run `xcode-select --install`；

run `brew install git`,

[image]

If you got this result as above picture. Refer to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237537/brew-doctor-warning-how-to-add-git-to-path/38408656)

At last, run `brew install ipython`

Answer (score 2):

I use `pip3 install ipython` is OK.

maybe `ipython` rely on `python3`

Answer (score 0):

After trying to a number of solutions like above with out joy, when I restarted my terminal, Ipython command launched. Don't forgot to restart your terminal after all the fiddling!

P.S. I think the `brew install Ipython` did it ... but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that helped was:
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Upgrading pip did the work and all the installations started working properly!
Give it a try.

Comment: Artem R U Sure?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to find the `ipython` launcher script that was created when installing ipython via pip and use it.

Find where `ipython` is by running:

```bash
find / -name ipython
```

You may have to add sudo: `sudo find / -name ipython`

In my case (macOS: Ventura 3.13, python 3.11 ) this returned:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/ipython`

Verify that this `ipython` script works as expected.

Run the whole path in the terminal:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/ipython`.
You should see the ipython console prompt

[image: console screenshot of ipython]

Next, you need to tell your mac that the command `ipython` means in fact `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/ipython`. You do that by creating a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/` to the real location  of `ipython` with `ln -s <source file> <target file>`.

In the terminal run:

```bash
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/ipython /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

And `ipython` now starts an ipython session

[image: ipython starts the ipython console]