# ipython on MacOS 10.10 - command not found

Tags: python, path, installation, ipython

I'm trying to get ipython working in Mac OS 10.10.

*problem:*

```
$ ipython
```

returns

```
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

*context:*

I'm running python2.7 on MacOS 10.10.  I installed python via brew. Some info:

`which python` =

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

`brew info python` =

```
python: stable 2.7.10 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2 (4977 files, 77M) *
```

To install ipython I ran

```
pip install ipython[all]
```

so... `pip show ipython =`

```
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: ipython
Version: 4.0.0
Summary: IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
Home-page: http://ipython.org
Author: The IPython Development Team
Author-email: ipython-dev@scipy.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: traitlets, pickleshare, simplegeneric, decorator, gnureadline, appnope, pexpect
```

finally, `echo $PATH =`

```
/Users/[username]/depot_tools:/usr/local:/usr/local/lib:/Users/[username]/depot_tools:/usr/local:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Users/[username]/depot_tools:/usr/local:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/git/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does `python -m IPython --version` print?

Comment: @cel - it shows 4.0.0

Comment: That means, that you successfully installed ipython, (you can call it by `python -m IPython`). However for some reason you did not get a symlink. Reinstalling may help.

Comment: @cel, thanks I have tried this, several times. I could just create the symlink but now I can't seem to find the binary.

Comment: there are no binaries. the executable binary is just a python script. You could set a shell alias `ipython` to `python -m IPython`.

Comment: interesting.  Was there a binary for v 3?

Comment: @cel's comments here helped me answer a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34457373/99127), so I've tried to pay it forward by upvoting cel's comments to this post. I wish I understood what's causing the wrapper script to be missing, though! This seems to be a fairly common problem on OSX.

Answer (score 8):

I met the same issue but resolved.  You need to make sure install IPython at first via this command on terminal.

```
$python -m IPython
```

Then it will show this result:
[image]

Congratulations! You had IPython in your computer.

Then run this command on terminal.

```
alias ipython='python -m IPython'
```

Finally you can try ipython command again.

You can add this command line into **~/.bash_profile** file for permanent.
It works fine for me.

Comment: Note that Python 2 has been finally declared dead as of 2020. Install IPython system-wide with `sudo -H pip3 install ipython` and then set up the alias as recommended above, but like `alias python3 -m IPython`.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to install *jupyter* with 'pip install jupyter'.
http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Then I got similar error on running ipython.
I did try all solutions on Stackoverflow about installing ipython.

At last, I installed **[Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)** then run `conda install jupyter`.
Now everything works fine.

My environment:

1. Python 2.7
2. Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: works great! Thanks! Just a note, I need to install the Anaconda under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages in order to get it to work.