# Unable to find ipython after installation on Mac

Tags: python, macos, ipython

I installed ipython using pip. I have python 2.7 on my Mac. However I am unable to start up ipython.

[17:26:01] ipython
-bash: ipython: command not found

Then thinking that maybe I need to run it from within python I even tried that

[17:28:10] python 
import ipython 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named ipython

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here

[IPython command not found Terminal OSX. Pip installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745923/ipython-command-not-found-terminal-osx-pip-installed)

that worked for me. Courtesy @nudzo.

"Create .pydistutils.cfg in your homedir with following content:

[global]
verbose=1

[install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin

[easy_install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin
And then: pip install -U --user ipython. Of course $HOME/bin must be in your $PATH. Packages are going to be installed in $HOME/Library/Python, so user only, not system wide."

I uninstalled ipython and then followed these instructions and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these shell commands.  I'm using Debian, & don't have a Mac.

**which ipython**

Should show the dir where it is installed, eg, /usr/bin/ipython

**echo $PATH**

Should show a list of paths where the system looks for programs to execute; it should include the location of ipython, eg, /usr/bin for my example above.

**pip list**

Should include 'ipython' in the list of installed pkgs.

**pip show ipython**

Should show data about the installed ipython pkg.

Your home directory should have  a dir called '.ipython' if the pkg was installed (unless it was put somewhere else).

If you don't find the program, maybe the install failed.  Try again and watch for error messages.

Comment: I found the installation here /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/  but cannot find a bin directory or an executable that will help me run ipython. How do I run it from here?

Comment: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745923/ipython-command-not-found-terminal-osx-pip-installed that worked for me. I'll post that as the answer here.