# brew doctor Warning: How to add git to PATH?

Tags: git, macos, path, homebrew

I installed Homebrew on OS X El Capitan. In the last steps of the installation I was supposed to install git with

```
brew install git
```

which was fine. Now if I run 'brew doctor' this happens:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Git could not be found in your PATH.
Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae use Git
checkouts instead of stable tarballs. You may want to install Git:
  brew install git
```

If I run 'brew install git' again, I get:

```
$ brew install git 
Warning: git-2.7.4 already installed
```

So needless to say my git version is 2.7.4. 'brew update' throws:

```
$ brew update
Warning: git-2.7.4 already installed
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
```

**Question:** How do I fix my PATH so git can be found in my PATH and 'brew doctor' results in 'Your system is ready to brew'?

---

Additional Information:

- which -a git results in:

  ```
  $ which -a git
  /usr/local/bin/git
  /usr/local/bin/git
  /usr/bin/git
  ```
- I tried a lot of potential fixes, meanwhile I executed:

  ```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  ```

  My ~/.bash_profile now looks like this:

  ```
  # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
  # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
  PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  ```
- When I try to install cask:

  ```
  $ brew tap caskroom/cask
  ==> Installing git
  Warning: git-2.7.4 already installed
  Error: Git is unavailable
  ```
- brew config:

  ```
  $ brew config
  HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
  ORIGIN: (none)
  HEAD: (none)
  Last commit: never
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
  HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
  HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
  HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
  CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
  OS X: 10.11.4-x86_64
  Xcode: 7.3
  CLT: 7.3.0.0.1.1457485338
  Clang: 7.3 build 703
  X11: N/A
  System Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
  Perl: /usr/bin/perl
  Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
  Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  Java: 1.8.0_40
  ```

EDIT: Added cask to additional information.

EDIT2: Added brew config and added brew doctor prefix

Comment: Please also post the full output of `brew doctor` and `brew config`.

Comment: @bfontaine I added the `brew config` and completed the `brew doctor` (the general note about homebrew warnings, which I considered as unimportant in the first place).

Comment: Thanks; does `source ~/.bash_profile` fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried it 2 days ago along with TheGeorgeous' approach, but it didn't work. I also tried it a few seconds ago, `brew doctor` still provides the same output

Comment: What is the output of `brew info git`?

Comment: I fixed it, see my accepted answer. Thanks for your help @bfontaine!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, change directory to `/usr/local/Homebrew` in the Terminal (for older versions of MacOS, use `cd cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew`). Then run:

```
git pull origin master
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: for newer version of MacOS use `cd /usr/local/Homebrew` path instead

Answer (score 14):

For me this was caused by missing xcode tools, fixed by `xcode-select --install`.

Several other suggested fixes including `git fetch` in the brew directory and/or changing git `core.autocrlf` did not fix this.

In more detail I uninstalled git from brew `brew uninstall --force git`, but Apple's own git then didn't work (`/usr/bin/git --version` reported `missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`).

Running `brew doctor` suggested running `xcode-select --install`, I ran this and it fixed Apple's git, and also fixed brew. (Possible to then reinstall git via brew `brew install git`.)

Comment: I just updated to macOS Mojave and I had to reinstall the Xcode command-line tools to get brew (and git) going again

Comment: This works and is the answer for me. Why is the "answer" doing a git pull manually, when the whole essence of using a package manager is not to do anything manually, even for homebrew. Tsk tsk

Answer (score 1):

Simply run:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Your `PATH` variable should look something like

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately; I ran the command `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` but this didn't change anything in my ~/.bash_profile. After that I manually changed the ~/.bash_profile to look like this:
   
`PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"`
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

If I completely misunderstood your answer, be gentle. I don't have that much experience with unix terminals

Comment: Have you checked your `.bashrc`? Also you will have to run `source .bashrc` to reload your configuration

Comment: If I run `source .bashrc`it says `No such file or directory`. I simply closed and reopened my terminal to reload the configuration. As far as I know, in this case I only have to look for the .bash_profile and set the PATH correctly so the git will be found by brew?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. It was caused by a wrong fileformat of `/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git`:

```
$ /usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git --version
-bash: /usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So I edited the fileformat:

```
$ vi /usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git
```

Press 'ESC', write `:set fileformat=unix`, Press 'Enter', write `:wq!`.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me: using macOS El Capitan and don't have `/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git`, here's what you can do.

```
cd /usr/local/
# The folder where you've installed Homebrew
git config --list --local
```

Look for: `core.autoxrlf=false`

If don't see it run: `git config --local core.autocrlf false`

Then run:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same symptom when tyring to run `brew update`.

In my case problem was caused by have a bash variable of `GIT` set (to a directory). So the solution was to unset it for the brew command

```
$ GIT= brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely problem with libintl.8.dylib as in many other similar issues:

```
locate libintl.8.dylib
```

if */gettext/*/libintl.*.dylib exists

```
brew link -f gettext
```

go to (depending on version)

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew 
cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
```

and execute (make sure you're in .../Homebrew directory)

```
git pull origin master
rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
brew update && brew upgrade
```

this last will took some time, but afterwards everything should work fine.