# Problems with Git when installing Homebrew: "Error: Git is unavailable"

Tags: git, homebrew

This is what I get when I try to install Homebrew: [Error: Git is unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oIt9.png)

> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
> Error: Git is unavailable

It gives me an error and says that Git is unavailable, although I have downloaded Git and installed it.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have your brew updated.
First run the following command:

```
brew doctor
```

Now, if you get `Your system is ready to brew`, you can move on to install Git.

With Homebrew, installing Git is as easy as this:

```
brew update
brew install git
```

Note: it's a good habit to run update before installing anything with Homebrew because Homebrew is updated regularly.

To verify:

```
git --version
```

You should get `git version 2.3.1` or later.

Run `brew doctor` to make sure everything is still working.
In case `brew doctor` doesn't work you can use these commands:

```
cd `brew --prefix`
git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Already up-to-date.

If you're seeing permission errors tried running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)
```

Or if it complains that any directories inside `/usr/local` aren't writable, fix it with this command:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

Lastly, if you get Warning: `/usr/bin` occurs before `/usr/local/bin`, run the command below and quit and relaunch Terminal:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

This command takes everything between the single quotes and adds it `>>` to a file called `.bash_profile` in your user's root directory `~/`. Every time you open a new Terminal window or tab, `.bash_profile` is called. The export `PATH` line tells your system to look in `/usr/local/bin` first, since that's where Homebrew installs tools.

### Download and Install the Command Line Tools

For El Capitan, Yosemite and Mavericks

1. Inside the Terminal window, copy and paste (or type) the following command, and press the return key on your keyboard:

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
2. You should see the pop up below on your screen. Click Install when it appears.

[image: install xcode]

3. Click Agree when the License Agreement appears.
4. Your computer will then attempt to find the software, and then will start downloading it. The following popup will appear:
5. Once the software is installed, click Done. That's it! You're now ready to go to Step 2.

[image: install xcode, done]

Comment: when i try run brew doctor it returns with :
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q

Comment: in fact when i try to run any line with the command brew it returns with the same error

Also I downloaded Git 2.8.1 so the version should be fine

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you think that my answer was useful please give me a point. Thanks~

Comment: all the commands you wrote it returns they are illegal instructions :/

Comment: no I didn't.. where can i find versions to download compatible with my version? (10.6.8)

Comment: I've written an [open source script](https://github.com/teocci/DevLaptop) that can set everything up for you, including configuring your Mac to work with GitHub.

If you prefer to do everything manually, start with Install Step above.

Answer (score 5):

So the `PATH` was getting filtered, setting

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1
```

helped avoid this issue

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I tried all the suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237537/brew-doctor-warning-how-to-add-git-to-path

Comment: As of 2022, this is the only solution that worked for me for a 2019 Macbook Air.

Comment: Error: HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING was deprecated for over a year and has now been removed (because it breaks many things)!

Answer (score 0):

If you see the message "Error: Git is unavailable" it usually means that the git part of the brew installation is broken. To have a better hint of what's wrong with your installation, try running this:

```
ls -ld `brew --prefix`/.git
```

If you downloaded brew from git, then obviously you already have git. So this error means you have a broken $PATH or broken brew symlink or something wonky with your brew installation.

I also had this error, but after I fixed my $PATH to ensure the good brew was first, then this error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue

1. Run ‘xcode-select --install‘ (let the installation complete)
2. ‘brew update’
3. ‘brew install “postman” or